# How to setup a database driven login permission system Linux

Tags: linux, opensuse

For a kind of Internet Café we want to do the following:

- People buy access for their username for a specific time period. E.g. the coming hour.
- The coming hour they can log in on an OpenSuse box
- After the hour the system automatically logs out the user
- The user can not log in anymore

How to set this up?

(Later we maybe want to add a warning 5 minutes before shutting of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use LDAP instead of a database in combination with a logout script timed by at(d).

Some maybe usefull code snippets:

Timed logout:

```
at 13:37 -f logout.sh
at now + 1 hour -f logout.sh
```

Command to force logout:

```
kill -15 $(ps -U NameOfUserToLogout -o "pid=")
```